# NS3 and WAF compatibility

Tags: ns-3

File "/home/~/ns-allinone-3.33/ns-3.33/.waf3-2.0.21-c6c9a875365426e5928462b9b74d40b5/waflib/TaskGen.py", line 123, in post
v()
File "/home/~/ns-allinone-3.33/ns-3.33/src/wscript", line 724, in apply_ns3moduleheader
for source in sorted(ns3headers.headers):
AttributeError: 'task_gen' object has no attribute 'headers'

***Is it something incompatible between ns-3.33 and waf3-2.0.21?  Is there a solution to the problem?***

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

ns-3.33 uses Waf version 2.0.21.  I'm guessing that the error you are seeing is from adding some code that is not compatible with ns-3.33?  Do you get this error from downloading and building a fresh copy of the ns-3.33 release?  **Note:**  most questions such as these are handled in the ns-3-users@googlegroups.com forum.